# Fastest way to transfer data from SQL to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, sql, import

I frequently have to use large tables and results from MS SQL in ArcMap and for that saving the data as .xls is one of the options. But when I add the data to arcmap, processes like joining and plotting the data take a lot of time. My question is that what would be the fastest method of importing SQL data into Arcmap and then working on it?

Comment: how are your geographic data stored in your MS SQL table? X,Y columns or MS SQL spatial types?

Comment: As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  You left out the version of ArcGIS, but the only rule broken was the chit-chat PS apologizing for breaking rules.  Oh, and welcome to GIS SE.

Comment: @FaridCher the data has postcode and certain values for it. I then import this data and join it with a postcode shapefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to get SQL query to ArcMap (10.1 and later) is to use a Query layer.

> Menu File > Add Data > Add Query Layer

Before further question please also refer to the Manual relevant to your version (RTFM!)
Manual entry : **What is a query layer?** [10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000000n000000), [10.2.x](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000000n000000) or [10.3 (latest)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/what-is-a-query-layer-.htm)

ESRI support manual changed since latest release, this is why I provided you those 3 links.
Query layer had become easier and easier to set up with each release especially for me who work with PostGIS.

You could also read this other manual section [about database connections (10.3)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/databases/database-connections-desktop.htm) 
(please look for yourself for previous manual version if needed ;)

Comment: This worked well for me. Thanks!
But when I join this data with a shapefile and Classify the data, it takes a lot of time in reading the data (about 30k rows) and defining bins for it. Is there a way to speed up this process as well?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your dataset is huge and contain complex objects, the realtime connection will be slow when you try to display the whole dataset at the same time. If realtime data is not needed you can just transfers the data from the query layer to a feature class in a local geodatabase (using right click or the toolbox "convert feature classe to feature class" somewhat more reliable an automatizable if needed.

Comment: Also please remember to upvote and mark the answer as solved if your problem is solved ;)