# display shapefile from postgres using arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcmap, shapefile, postgresql

I have uploaded shapefile using postgis extension in postgres but when i tried to display the shapefile in arcmap, it wont display the data in vector.

this is the image of my connection.
[image]

i followed the steps from this link ; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0W1ZgU8GkQ
as you can see, when the data from postgres is dragged into table of contant it should display the vector of the data. but mine just wont show up, really hope anyone can help if im missing something.

Comment: Can you specify which version of ArcGis and postgis you are using?

Comment: Once a shapefile is loaded into PostgreSQL it is no longer a shapefile -- it's a table. Referring to the table as a "shapefile" actually increases the complexity of the problem, because it means you're looking in the wrong place in the documentation for help. Please **edit** the question to embed the image in the question (links often go unfollowed) and explain your actual procedure (video links are even less likely to be followed)

Comment: Also after watching your video I must say that in real world, thing never get as easy in ArcMap. My favored way of connecting ArcMap to Postgis is query layers which I already discussed in this answer (also see related manual reference that I gave) : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164890/fastest-way-to-transfer-data-from-sql-to-arcmap/164945#164945